# Bootstrap form displays linebreak Early

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/scander/25exnvtg/2/ for Code. It looks like the form puts a horizontal line accross the address field instead of at the end of form. How can I fix that? It seems like the address instruction field is causing it.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal">Self-Certify</a></h1>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Section 3 Resident Self-Certification and Skills</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <row>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control name" placeholder="First name" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 2 characters long, and must only contain letters." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>MI</label>
                            <input class="form-control mid" placeholder="" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Middle Inital can only be 1 character long." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-5">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control Lastname" placeholder="Last name" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 2 characters long, and must only contain letters." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                    </row>
          <row>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-0"></label>
             <div class="col-sm-12"> <p class="form-control-static">Home Address (must be a street address and not a P.O. Box number)</p></div>
          </div>
          </row>       
          <row>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control address" placeholder="123 Main Street" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid address." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Apt#</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
                        </div></div>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>City</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="City" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 2 characters long, and must only contain letters." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>State</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="WI" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Zip</label>
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 2 characters long, and must only contain letters." type="text">
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>County</label>
                       <div class="ui-select">
                <select id="County" class="form-control">

                            <option>Milwaukee</option>
                            <option>Waukesha</option>
                            <option>Ozaukee</option>
                             <option>Washington</option>
                         </select>
                        </div></div>
                    </row>

          <row>
            <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-6"><label>E-Mail</label><input class="form-control email" placeholder="email@you.com (so that we can contact you)" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address (user@gmail.com)" type="text"></div></div>
            <div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-6"><label>Phone</label><input class="form-control phone" placeholder="999-999-9999" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid phone number (999-999-9999)" type="text"></div></div>
          </row>  
          <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send It!</button> <p class="help-block pull-left text-danger hide" id="form-error">&nbsp; The form is not valid. </p></div>
        </form>




      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *It looks like the form puts a line break on address instead of the end of form*

Comment: I put an instruction element in the form that causes the end form line to display before it should. It displays as a line going thru the address and apt# field. I don't know how to fix it so it displays after email /phone. but before the buttons

Answer (score 0):

It is the element that you have before the instructions that is causing a new line. 
**EDIT**: I meant to say it is the <label> element that is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do think you are right. Is there a way to add those instructions without the form displaying that line?

Comment: I think it should be okay to get rid of the label element since it's not really a  form label, but instruction text.

Comment: Are you talking about a new line or a horizontal line at the end of the form? I apologize, I might have understood your question wrong.

Comment: I do apologize for wording my question incorrectly. I am struggling with adding the instructions and keeping the horizontal line at the end of the form.